# Connection between a local machine and a virtual machine

Tags: virtualization

I'm running a Linux VM under Mac OS. It'd like to establish a connection between the physical machine and the VM. To do that, I need my Mac's IP address so I can ping it. Which interface's address should I configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of virtualization are your running? You probably just need to configure the networking in whichever virtualization product you're using. I'd assume that if you are already using your Mac, that there is already an IP address configured on it.

Comment: I'm running VirtualBox. And the only thing I found that looked like a local address (IPv4) was assigned to the Ethernet interface.

Comment: Is that on your Mac? The local Ethernet interface probably your primary interface. You should already have an address assigned to your Mac, and then you can use ifconfig on your linux box to configure an IP address on it. Then you should be able to ping back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a VM can be setup with a bridged network connection,appearing on the same network as your host, or NAT, where it lives on it's own internal network.

If you need to connect to your host's IP address, bridging is the easiest method. It may also be possible to use the virtual gateway address through NAT